# For some reason my background image is not displaying

Tags: reactjs, background

For some reason none of the questions or online videos online is helping me solve my issue. This is my code below and its still displaying my page without an image. If anyone can help me see whats wrong that would be great.

```
import { Image, Text } from 'react-native';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class BackgroundImage {
render() {
    return (
        <Image source={require('../../images/showcase.jpg')} style= 
{styles.backgroundImage}>
            {this.props.children}
        </Image>
    );
}
}

class TestBackgroundImage extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <BackgroundImage>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Fullscreen!</Text>
        </BackgroundImage>
    );
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
backgroundImage: {
    flex: 1,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    resizeMode: 'cover'
},

text: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: 'white',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    fontSize: 32
}
});

const Home = () => (
<div>
    <h2>Home page</h2>
</div>
);

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you are setting width and height `null`. height and width must have value, otherwise image doesn't shows. Please try to assign value of height and width e.g.

```
backgroundImage: {
 flex: 1,
 width: 50,
 height: 50,
 resizeMode: 'cover'
},
```

Comment: that didnt seem to do anything but tell me image is not defined, component is not defined, and text is not defined

Comment: These are undefined because are not importing them. You can try on top of file

`import {Image, Text } from 'react-native'`
`import React, {Component} from 'react'`

Comment: still no luck on image showing up. I installed react-native and says cannot resolve react-native but I know for a fact its installed!

Comment: Have you tried removing node_modules and reinstalling them?

Comment: Please run ‘npm i react-native’. Cannot resolve means package is not available in node_modules. By default node_modules is checked for modules. Also check manually if node_modules contains react-native

Comment: Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native' in 'c:\Users\mratt\Documents\UCF\project\findmyevent2.0\client\src\components\pages\Home' but I manually checked and there was react-native in there. Updated my code above as well

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to import the Image component in BackGroundImage and BackGroundImage in TestBackgroundImage?

```
// In BackGroundImage.js
import Image from 'path';
// In TestBackgroundImage.js
import BackGroundImage from 'path';
```

and I think, you want to show all components in Home component.
so

```
//import all components in Home.js
const Home = ()=> {
 return {
   <BackgroundImage/>
   <TestBackgroundImage/>
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using image use ImageBackGround directly

```
      class BackgroundImage {
          render() {
                return (
                   <ImageBackground source={require('../../images/showcase.jpg')} style= 
               {styles.backgroundImage}>
        {this.props.children}
    </ImageBackground>
      );
    }
 }
```